# Magento2 Mini Cart (Drop Down) Issue with Multistore website

Tags: php, magento2

I am facing a problem with Mini Cart (Drop Down)- Recent Added Items DropDown

We have the setup of multistore. suppose we are adding 1 item to the cart from store1 and 2nd item from store2. Minicart DropDown shows only 1 items from store2. It is showing the only item added from that store on which you are right now. But when you click on View Cart button all items will be displayed.

URL1:- http://futsole1.nufoot.com/ (add 1 product from this store)

URL 2:- http://new1.nufoot.com/women/mary-janes.html (add 2 products from this store)

Now do check mini cart dropdown on the top header. Please find attached screen for your reference.

I investigated the issue using (Inspect Element) problem is that only items from the current store are loading on the mini cart drop down, where it should load all items added to the cart. Please suggest the solution.

Hope you understand the problem, please let me know if you have any question Or suggest the solution.

[image]

Thanks